# How can I check number of elements on a select list and disable radio button?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to:

- disable radio button (with name 'advertisementType') when select list (with name 'updateAdvertisement') has got only 1 element
- disable submit button (with name 'saveButton') when selected option on select list has got null value

How can I do that in angular?

This is my html:

```
<div ng-controller="AdvertisementCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="save()">

        <input type="radio" ng-model="advertisementType" name="advertisementType" value="false">Update<br />

        <select ng-model="updateAdvertisement" name="updateAdvertisement" ng-show="advertisementType == 'false'">
            <option value>Select item</option>
            <option value="1">Volvo</option>
            <option value="2">Saab</option>
            <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="4">Audi</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="saveButton" ng-disabled="saveButton" />

    </form>
</div>
```

This is my javascript (but I have no idea):

```
<script>
    function AdvertisementCtrl($scope) {

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="AdvertisementCtrl">

    <form ng-submit="save()">

        <input type="radio" ng-model="advertisementType" name="advertisementType" ng-disabled='carTypes.length<=1' value="false">Update<br />

        <select ng-model="updateAdvertisement" name="updateAdvertisement" ng-options="item.type for item in carTypes">
            <option value>Select item</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="saveButton" ng-disabled="!updateAdvertisement" />

    </form>

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function AdvertisementCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.carTypes = [
        {id:'1', type:'Volvo'},
        {id:'2', type:'Saab'},
        {id:'3', type:'Mercedes'},
        {id:'4', type:'Audi'}
    ]
}
```

The JSFiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/7Jw9B/

Comment: Also, when you're retrieving the current value of the selected list, Angular will give you the entire selected object instead of just a value.  So in your save() function, you can retrieve the id of the currently selected item by referencing $scope.updateAdvertisement.id or if you want the name, it's $scope.updateAdvertisement.type.  See updated jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/7Jw9B/1/

Answer (score 0):

1. Populate the select from an array that you declare in the controller
2. Check array length and disable the radio button when array length is 1
3. Disable saveButton based on the value of updateAdvertisement

   ```
   <script>
   function AdvertisementCtrl($scope) {
       $scope.cars = ['Volvo', 'Saab', 'Mercedes', 'Audi', 'BMW'];
   }
   </script>
   ```

Markup:

```
   <div ng-controller="AdvertisementCtrl">
       <form ng-submit="save()">
       <input type="radio" ng-model="advertisementType" name="advertisementType" value="false" ng-disabled="cars.length <= 1">Update<br />
       <select ng-model="updateAdvertisement" name="updateAdvertisement" ng-show="advertisementType == 'false'" ng-options="cars">
       </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Save" name="saveButton" ng-disabled="updateAdvertisement" />
       </form>
   </div>
```

Should probably be tested in a fiddle :-), could do that later

Comment: Thx but rchawdry solution is better ;)